# How can I create an LVM volume group spanning 2 hard drives?

Tags: centos, partition, hard-disk, lvm

I have rented a dedicated server with two 500gb hardisks running Centos 6.

On this server there are 4 partitions:

```
1.boot
2.root 50gb
3.swap 50gb4.
4.empty 400gb
```

Now I want to create a logical volume group spanning the empty 400gb on the first disk and merge it with the empty 400gb on the second disk.

I've read tutorial after tutorial but I cannot understand how to accomplish this task. I just want to merge the empty partition with the empty disk.

Can someone please outline the steps to accomplish this, or please tell me if it is at all possible?

Comment: If you have only four partitions on this server, and given the sizes, it looks like the second harddisk is not partitioned yet. Start with that (using `fdisk`, `parted`, `gparted`, etc.). BTW, asking if someone can suggest something can only *correctly* be answered by Yes (or No), that is probably not going to help, so don't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: As a fair warning, you need to be careful when having logical volumes span across multiple disks. If one fails, you lose your entire volume group. I cannot stress this enough, there is a **huge** possibility of you losing your data if a drive fails *or* you delete a partition that's part of the volume group.

You need to create a partition on both disks for the free space you have. You can use `fdisk` or `parted`. I personally use `fdisk`.

```
# fdisk -cu /dev/sda
```

1. You will want to create a new partition by pressing `n`, and let it select all the defaults.
2. Press `t`, select partition `4`, and set it to `8e`, which is LVM.
3. Press `w` to save.

You will need to do the same for your other disk, this is more than likely `/dev/sdb`. Create a new partition, let it be the defaults so it takes the whole disk.

**You will need to reboot after you make changes to your primary disk!**

Afterwards, you need to create a "physical volume".

```
# pvcreate /dev/sda4
```

Do this for the two partitions you created. Now create a Volume Group. Replace your device names and numbers according to what you have in your setup.

```
# vgcreate VolGroup01 /dev/sda4 /dev/sdb4
```

This will create a volume group that spans those two partitions, across those two disks. Now, you can create a logical volume.

```
# lvcreate VolGroup01 -n LogVolOpt -L200G
(I decided to format mine with ext4)
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/VolGroup01/LogVolOpt
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can just call `vgcreate` to create a volume group directly and proceed to create logical volumes. No other step is necessary. In particular running `pvcreate` in advance is not necessary. Also, the poster said the partitions already exist, so creating them is redundant.

Comment: Brilliant Sokel! Exacatly what I needed! Thank you for such a cler and detailed explanation! Worked like a charm! Thanks again man. :)